# Does usage of "to" depend on the verb or object?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, indirect-objects, thematic-role

> I give to you a pen.

In the above sentence I am using "to" before the object "you".

> I am giving you a pen.

In the above sentence I am not using "to" before the object "you".

In the above two sentences the usage of "to" depends on the verb forms ("give" and "giving") or object ("you").

> I give you a pen.
>
> I am giving to you a pen.
>
> I have given you a pen.
>
> I have given to you a pen.

Are the above four sentences correct?

If I want to use "to" in a sentence before a noun or pronoun, what do I have to consider before "to" what I have used or after "to" what I am going to use.

Is it possible to use "to" before an adverb or adjective?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let’s start by distinguishing the *thematic* roles in this sentence, the roles played by the actual entities named with respect to the actual action described by the verb, and the *syntactic* roles, the formal roles played by the words with respect to the structure of the sentence.

In your examples, *a pen* has a thematic role linguists call **T**heme, the thing which is ‘acted upon’, and the syntactic role **D**irect **O**bject.  I’ll notate that like this, with the abbreviation for the thematic role in superscript after the word and the abbreviation for the syntactic role before the word:

> <sub>DO</sub>a pen<sup>T</sup>

*You*, the person who receives the thing given, is assigned the thematic role **R**ecipient. That thematic role is the same throughout; but that role is expressed syntactically in two different ways:

- The Recipient may be expressed as a noun phrase: a bare pronoun like *you* or a fuller phrase like *my friend Mary*. In this case we call its syntactic role an **O**bject—specifically, an **I**ndirect **O**bject.

  > <sub>IO</sub>you<sup>R</sup> … <sub>IO</sub>my friend Mary<sup>R</sup>
- The Recipient may also be expressed with a preposition phrase (PP) headed by *to*: *to you*, *to my friend Mary*. In this case, we do not call the PP an Object but a **C**omplement.

  > <sub>C</sub>to you<sup>R</sup> … <sub>C</sub>to my friend Mary<sup>R</sup>

Whether ***to*** is used—whether the Recipient is expressed as an **IO** or as a **C**—determines how your sentence is laid out.

A Recipient expressed as an **IO**  comes **before** the **DO**, the Theme.

> I gave [<sub>IO</sub>you<sup>R</sup>] [<sub>DO</sub>a pen<sup>T</sup>].
>
> John is giving [<sub>IO</sub>Mary<sup>R</sup>] [<sub>DO</sub>a ring<sup>T</sup>].

The order of the two Objects tells us which is the **IO** and which the **DO**, and that in turn lets us know which is the Recipient and which the Theme.

But suppose you want to put your Recipient **after** your Theme? In this case you have to express **R** as a **C**, as a PP with *to*, since the position no longer makes it clear what role the noun phrase plays in the sentence:

> I gave [<sub>DO</sub>a pen<sup>T</sup>] [<sub>C</sub>**to** you<sup>R</sup>] .
>
> John is giving [<sub>DO</sub>a ring<sup>T</sup>] [<sub>C</sub>**to** Mary<sup>R</sup>].

The same holds with other verbs which take Indirect Objects, such as *say* or *serve*:

> The waiter has served [<sub>IO</sub>the party<sup>R</sup>] [<sub>DO</sub>dinner<sup>T</sup>]. ... The waiter has served [<sub>DO</sub>dinner<sup>T</sup>] [<sub>**C**</sub>**to** the party<sup>R</sup>].
>
> I will tell [<sub>**IO**</sub>the police<sup>R</sup>] [<sub>**DO**</sub>my story<sup>T</sup>]. ... I will tell [<sub>DO</sub>my story<sup>T</sup>] [<sub>C</sub> **to** the police<sup>R</sup>].

In all these sentences, the Recipient is the person or party who *receives* the action. An Recipient may also be the person or party who is the *beneficiary* of the action; in that case the proper preposition is *for*, not *to*, but otherwise the same rules apply:

> George is building [<sub>IO</sub>his daughter<sup>R</sup>] [<sub>DO</sub>a house<sup>T</sup>]. ... George is building [<sub>DO</sub>a house<sup>T</sup>] [<sub>C</sub>**for** his daughter<sup>R</sup>].

Answer (score 0):

You're putting the preposition in the wrong place. It would be better to use either:

- *I gave you a pen*, or
- *I gave a pen to you*.

The word *to* has [too many meanings and usages](http://www.onelook.com/?w=to&ls=a) to come up with concrete rules about using it before other parts of speech.

That said, when *to* is used before a noun, there is often an article included:

- I am going to the store.
- The outfielder tossed the ball to a fan.
- The firemen rushed to the fire.

Also, it can be used in front of an adverb when it would otherwise be put in front of a verb, though the adverb can also come after the verb as well. Compare:

- We are going to shop for new pants.
- We are going to hurriedly shop for new pants.
- We are going to shop hurriedly for new pants.