# "Send me that" or "Send that"

Tags: grammar, objects

I am bit confused of the following sentences.

> Send me that book.

or

> Send that book.

The same way, *Courier me that book* or *Courier that book*.

Which is correct? Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Related (direct object, indirect object): http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/6319/3281.

Comment: Dative alternation: "Send **me** that book." and "Send that book **to me**."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Send me that book" or "Send that book to me" both specify that you want the person to whom you are speaking to send the book, and the desired recipient is yourself.

"Send that book" says that you want the book sent, but doesn't specify a destination. Hopefully the desired destination would be clear from context.

"Courier that book" and "Courier me that book" do not make sense. Neither sentence includes a verb. Perhaps you are thinking that "courier" is a verb? It is not: it is a noun, referring to someone who personally delivers messages or packages. You could say, "Send that book by courier."

Courier is also the name of a common font, though that definition seems even less likely to be what you have in mind. You could say, "Change the font of that book to Courier" or "Typeset that book using Courier."

Comment: @Theta30 I'm not sure I've heard it used as a verb before.  If it is a verb, it must be either uncommon or part of a dialect I don't speak.

Comment: Well, okay. I've never heard it used that way, and I dictionaried it in several places before keyboarding this post. I suppose any noun can be verbed like that. I opinion that by that standard there is no such thing as a "part of speech", as all words can be parted any way you like.